# I can't run basic C++ program " Hello World " in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm learning C++ as first programming language and I can't figure out how to run Hello World program. I was googling for solution but I did not find any.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Unable to start program
'C:\Users/thom/Desktop/C++/Visual/firstproject/Debug/Hello World.exe'.
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to really begin troubleshooting, but I personally wouldn't use file names with spaces for command line, and also you have a mix of `\ ` and `/` which probably isn't right.

Comment: Did you build the program? Can _you_ find that executable? Was it even generated?

Comment: In C++, you need to convert the source code into an executable.  This is called building, but often called compiling.  Set your build mode to Debug, the build your program.

Comment: Also, you should get in the habit of appending "\n" to your text, so that the stream will be flushed.

Comment: *How* did you try to run the program? Did you verify that the file `C:\Users\thom\Desktop\C++\Visual\firstproject\Debug\Hello World.exe` does in fact exist?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a .cpp file in File > New > File > C++ File?

[image]

If so, the path is not included in the project directory, causing the compiler to fail to find the file.

[image]

The correct way is to create a cpp file in the project directory under Explorer.As shown below：

[image]

[image]

You can modify the name of the .cpp, and don't modify the default location.

Now you can try to build and run the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Try Build -> Rebuild Solution, find the executable in the path shown at the output to run it.
You can also try pressing Ctrl+F5 to build and run